# Create game sprites in Interface Builder?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

Something I'm not very clear on is whether I should/could use interface builder to create reusable game sprites. For example, if I have a ball that I want to create an indeterminate amount of at run time, should I be creating a nib file (and either attaching graphics in IB or drawing them in drawRect) with it's own viewcontroller class attached, then instantiating that (and adding its view) programatically?

If so, do I do this with loadNibNamed? I'm a bit confused with the approach when using Interface Builder to design game sprites and some advice on how to approach it would be appreciated.

I've tried finding answers myself, but I find Apple's documentation longwinded and confusing.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to build a game using sprites, I would suggest using Cocos2D, much more simple than all this nib files thing...
Here's a great Cocos2D tutorial:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/352/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-tutorial

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion, I will look into Cocos2D, although I feel it may be overkill for what I am trying to achieve, and I think adding an extra layer of complexity to something I am already struggling to understand may hinder me in the long run.

Comment: Not really, when I tried to learn iOS programming Cocos2D was much easier for me than this all Interface Builder thing.